# view size on iphone 5 screen incorrect

Tags: iphone, view, size, ios6, iphone-5

I am using in my app the view size to position a subview in code.

for example like this:

```
self.view.bounds.size.height
```

This subview has to be animated in and out of the view.

This has worked perfect on older devices, now I am trying to support iphone 5 and found out that I still get the height of the old devices.
Everything except this animated view adapts perfect for iphone 5.

The only way to get the right size is if I change the size of the view in the xib, downside is
that if I now run my app on iPhone 4 the view size is the 4inch view size.

What is the problem here?
Or is this the way it is supposed to be and I have to create an extra xib file for iPhone 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright so the answer is the following:

Like @mrwalker said make sure that the view automatically or programmatically resizes.

And be aware of the fact that the view is not yet resized in the `viedDidLoad` method.
(This was my mistake)

If you need the resized views size do your stuff in `viewWillAppear` there the view has already the right size.

thanks to @mrwalker and @AndyDev

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure your view is resized for the device it's running on. You could either:

1. Create a new Xib for the iPhone 5, as you might for an iPad
2. Have existing Xib automatically or programatically resize

I would only opt for (1) if you were intending on having a different layout (more / fewer buttons and such).

How you achieve (2) depends on whether you're using iOS 6's Auto Layout or the old autoresize model. Both methods can be controlled in the Utilities > Size Inspector in Xcode, or programatically.

If you have a single view & view controller, allowing the view to automatically resize to the parent window should be enough.

Comment: this sounds very reasonable. I have to support older versions so how would I do that? I have set struts and springs in IB to allow resizing if you mean that.My view takes the whole view on the iphone5 just the property size is wrong.

Comment: If you need to support old versions, stick with springs & struts (the old resize model). Is the window for your view the correct size? Perhaps you need to make sure the view's frame matches the superview (or window) bounds?

Comment: the parent is my app delegate where I set my VC as rootviewcontroller. The window of the delegate is obviously the right size but my VC view does not get resized correctly. why? and how and where would I set/check the VC view to the frame of the window of the superview/delegate ?

Comment: I think I'd need to see some code at this point. My guess is you need `self.viewController.view.frame = self.window.bounds;` right before `self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;`.

Comment: I just open a new project (Single View Application) thats the code I use. I tried your code, does not have any effect ;(

Comment: EDIT: It does have an effect BUT in the viewDidLoad method of my VC it does't cause this is called before I can change the size of the window

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where I wasn't getting the correct height and using the Autolayout / autoresize didn't achieve the desired effect. I used the following code to determine the screen size and made the changes based on this.

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector: @selector(scale)]) {
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);
    if(result.height == 1136){
        // iPhone 5 (1136px height)
    } else {
        // Not iPhone 5
    }
}
```

Comment: this code is awesome for some us cases and I will keep that code in mind but it does not quite solve my problem. thanks for sharing